# Remotely access MySQL with SSL using VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, encryption, ssl

Is there any way to encrypt `MySQL` connections through coding in `VB.NET` ?

Comment: To be frank I am just a QA. I have raised this issue to the developer and he's asking help from me to look for sources to start.

Comment: You have three questions with answers but you have not accepted any answers.  Don't forget to upvote and accept useful answers.

Comment: I wanted to upvote but couldn't since my reputation point is not sufficient. I have accepted your answer :). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not "through coding in VB.NET".

VB.Net must communicate using the MySQL communication protocol, which does not support encryption directly.

However, your VB.NET code *can* communicate securely with MySQL.

The [MySQL recommendation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/secure-connections.html) is to use SSL to secure communications at the transport layer.  That has nothing to do with VB.Net and everything to do with setting up the SSL connection and using an appropriate connection string (include `SSL Mode=Required` in the connection string).

For details see

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-tutorials-ssl.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. From the documentation "The standard configuration of MySQL is intended to be as fast as possible, so encrypted connections are not used by default." Does this mean the configuration only be done on the server side (without any changes on the client side )?

Comment: Okay I just get the see the last part of your post. I believe the SSL Mode = Required is the only modification required on the client side.

Comment: That is correct.  The server must still be compiled with SSL support.  On the server run the command `mysqld --ssl --help`.  If the server complains that it doesn't understand the option `--ssl` then the server doesn't support SSL.

Comment: One last question Eric. We have a web application (in ASP) which also accessing the MySQL server (it's a local connection so I don't think we need to encrypt this,correct me if I am wrong). If my new server compiled with SSL support, will this affect the web application-MySQL existing communication ? Many Thanks.

Comment: If you compile a server with SSL support, non-SSL connections still work (although one can set table permissions to require SSL if one so chooses, I believe).  If by "local connection" you mean on the same box, the security risk of not using SSL is minimal.